# d3 force element(node) mouseout is triggering when moves out of contained circle or text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The nodes in my d3js graph look something like this:

```
<g x="418.35228687205745" y="407.82418738913753" fill-opacity="1">

<circle x="-8" y="-8" width="16" height="16" r="5" class="secondary-node" stroke="#0b0080" fill="#0086d1">
</circle>

<text dx="8" dy=".25em" class="secondary-node" y="0" x="0" font-size="1em">Node
</text>

</g>
```

I've attached mouseover and mouseout events that modify the formatting of the cirle and text, both grow as does the spacing between them. 
When the mouse is moved into the space between the circle and the text, mouseout is triggered, which is not the behaviour I expected, as the mouse events are bound to the node using .on(), not to the circle and text, but they seem to cascade down, if that it the right term.

Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: That _is_ the behavior that is to be expected – mouseout occurs when the element is “left” by mouseover a child element as well. Look into mouseenter/mouseleave instead.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I saw that solution mentioned elsewhere, but I experienced the same behaviour with mouseenter/mouseleave

Comment: I'm assuming that you are referring to a `g` element that contains both circle and text that you're attaching your handler to. This is not an element as such and you'll get mouseleave events when you move out of any of the elements in the group, even though your cursor may still be in empty space within the extent of the group. You could add a transparent rectangle in the background and add the event handler to this.

Comment: Hmm. chrome inspector shows the mouseenter/leave listeners bound to the <g>, but also to the <circle> and <text>, although the <text> also hase a mouseover/out listeners (due to poshytip) which is why I was wondering about d3's .on() and 'cascading'. I should test binding to the group using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind the event to the node but you bind it to a DOM element, which in your case is the circle. I assume that  elements cannot take any event handlers. In your case you would need to bind the event to the circle and the text or [draw some kind of transparent background to your  (or node) to bind an event](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/DbpUoCrOlrw/6b3ze1GyP-UJ) onto.

Comment: From the script perspective, the event is "bound" using D3's .on()

`vis.selectAll("g")
.on("mouseenter", fade(.1))
.on("mouseleave",fade(1));` 

If I inspect the <g> element in chrome and look at event listeners, my mouseenter and mouseleave listeners are listed there, which would suggest that you can bind the event to the 'node'. (question of linguistics here? I think I was wrong to say 'node' when I mean 'group') I don't want it bound to the circle, so if I can't bind event listeners to a group, it looks like I'll have to do the background option.

Comment: Right, in this case binding to the group works. However, the group itself has no dimensions (is not an object) in the browser DOM. Thus, I am surprised that your example actually works. I'll try that myself as soon as I can.

Comment: Cool, Behaviour of SVG is new to me, so I'm all ears to hear your results. :) 
I think it "works" because the text and circle elements are triggering the mouse events. For the moment I've added pointer-events:none to the circle, this is an acceptable work-around to the functionality problem for the moment. That link was helpful, I'll accept your answer if nobody else has anything to say on the matter.
Now to my other question of the day, - disabling mouseovers while dragging.